# Add class to body on dynamic element, remove after clicking again anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to the `<body>` tag to make the cursor a crosshair when clicking a button. When I click any where on the page, I then want this class to be removed.

Currently I click the button, the class is added, and then removed straight away.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('body').addClass('changeCursor');
}

$('html').on('click', '.changeCursor', function(){
  $('body.changeCursor').removeClass('changeCursor');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's removed straight-away because the button click propagates to the `html` element after your button click handler adds the class to `body`. Then the `html` element's handler runs, finds `body.changeCursor`, and removes it.

Just stop propagation in the first handler:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  $('body').addClass('changeCursor');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  $('body').addClass('changeCursor');
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('html').on('click', '.changeCursor', function() {
  $('body.changeCursor').removeClass('changeCursor');
});
```

```css
.foo {
  display: none;
}
body.changeCursor .foo {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click me to add</button>
<p>Click here or anywhere but the button above to remove</p>
<p class="foo">I'm only showing when <code>body</code> has <code>changeCursor</code></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

There I've used `stopPropgation` which *only* stops propagation, but if you don't need the default action to occur, you can just `return false`, which does both `stopPropgation` *and* `preventDefault`:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('body').addClass('changeCursor');
  return false;
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('body').addClass('changeCursor');
  return false;
});

$('html').on('click', '.changeCursor', function() {
  $('body.changeCursor').removeClass('changeCursor');
});
```

```css
.foo {
  display: none;
}
body.changeCursor .foo {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click me to add</button>
<p>Click here or anywhere but the button above to remove</p>
<p class="foo">I'm only showing when <code>body</code> has <code>changeCursor</code></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```